# Circular dependency detected: ContentChild and Injector

Tags: angular

Hi I get the following warning:

> Circular dependency detected:
>
> modules\components\dropdown\tag-input-dropdown.component.ts ->
>
> modules\components\tag-input\tag-input.ts ->
>
> modules\components\dropdown\tag-input-dropdown.component.ts

tag-input is the parent and uses tag-input-dropdown as contentChild. tag-input-dropdown gets the parent using `Injector.get()`

I tried to make a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-circ-dep1) to isolate the problem but I don't get the warning there.

In this [github repos](https://github.com/Marcelh1983/ngx-chips) you can see the warning after cloning npm i, ng serve.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: the reason for circular dependency is obvious, in your parent you referenced child and in child you referenced parent

Comment: hmm that's right I just found it strange that the Stackblitz didn't give the warning but it does if  I run ng serve locally. I guess I'll just have to accept the warning

Comment: I think you should refactor your code, circular dependency is always bad even if it's not an issue with Angular.

Comment: @youri the good way to over come this is using interfaces, unfortunately angular doesn't accept interface to use in ViewChild and ChildContent

Comment: This is a TypeScript error. You have circular imports between the two files. Please update your question to show what you're doing with `@ContentChild()` and explain why you need to do it.